# Selenium IDE not recording anything

Tags: selenium

Below is the pagesource, Selenium IDE is not recording anything. Also, when I try to click the "TabBar:AccountTab_arrow" using xpath, it does not click on the arrow rather it click on the tab. There is a menu that gets displayed on click event of the arrow.

```
*<div id="mainTable" class="screen">
<div id="topDivision" style="height:100%">
<table class="contentTable" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td class="page_header">
<div id="page_header" class="page_header">
<img id="logo" src="images/logo.gif">
<div id="helpLogoutLinks">
<div id="topModetabs" class="modetabs">
<div id="QuickJump_container" class="navigator">
<span id="topModetabs_left" class="modetabs_left"></span>
<span id="topModetabs_middle" style="width: 3px;">
<div class="off" onmouseleave="if(window.DHTML) {DHTML.buttonLeave(this)}" onmouseenter="if(window.DHTML) {DHTML.buttonEnter(this)}">
<div class="off" onmouseleave="if(window.DHTML) {DHTML.buttonLeave(this)}" onmouseenter="if(window.DHTML) {DHTML.buttonEnter(this)}" classname="">
<span id="TabBar:AccountTab_left" class="tab_left_off"> </span>
<span id="TabBar:AccountTab_container" class="tab_middle_off">
<span class="menu_tab_off_left"></span>
<span id="menu_TabBar:AccountTab" class="menu_tab_off" onclick="event.cancelBubble = true;" onmouseover="MenuImpl_mouseOverMenu('TabBar:AccountTab')">
<a id="TabBar:AccountTab" class="menu_link_tab_off" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="Recorder.click(this);;Events.invokeEvent('TabBar:AccountTab_act', true);event.cancelBubble=true" onfocus="null">Account</a>
<a id="TabBar:AccountTab_arrow" onclick="MenuImpl_showMenu('TabBar:AccountTab')">
<span class="menu_arrow_tab_off" border="0"></span>
</a>*
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be because the elements you're trying to interact with, are within iframe. Selenium IDE doesn't record actions that are performed withing iframe.This is known issue, please go [here](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=6180&q=ide&colspec=ID%20Stars%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Milestone%20Owner%20Summary&start=100)

Comment: I checked it, elements are not in any frames.